# Autohotkey: Save variable into forum field

Tags: variables, com, autohotkey

I am trying to write an autohotkey script to fill an online forum using COM. My problem is that the username is incremented by numbers, so ideally I want to loop the script to fill the form 5 or 6 times.

Here is the autohotkey part I am struggling with:

```
number := 28
username = user%number%
wb.document.all.getElementById(username).value := "username"  ;HERE IS THE PROBLEM
number++
```

I have tried %username%, username without quotes, and with single quotes, and nothing seem to be working.

any ideas? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about com objects, but maybe `wb.document.all.getElementById(%username%).value := username`? - and be sure to test it out with a "usual" variable before like `abc := username`

Comment: thank you for the reply. The problem is with the assignment after the = sign. The id username works fine. assigning that field to variable username is not working.

Comment: um well yes it does. `abc := username` works fine (without quotes) and stores, when looping, "user28", "user29" and so on into that variable.

Comment: It worked... turns out it was the sleep time for the form to load. form was slower than Sleep 100 for some reason.

Now, the form loads, but it is only taking 1 field. so password and email are not being filled.

Comment: are you trying to assign your custom username variable (user28) to the "username" field or, is there a field called "user28" and you want to assign the text "username" to it? It's not clear what you're wanting, but it is clear that in your code you're assigning the literal text "username" to a field with an id of "user28".

Comment: Have you tried without the `all`  ... `wb.document.getElementById` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that username is an environment variable, which contains your user name if you don't set #NoEnv.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that popped out to me was **all** in you, I see Joe DF asked if you had tried without?

Second thing is you shouldn't have **""'s** around your Variable.

If you are doing multiple assignments you can enclose them in **()'s** like so:

```
:= (UserName "`n" Address "`n" PhoneNumber "`n" SocialSecurity)
```

If you are having problem's with a document not fully being loaded you can implement a custom loading routine like so:

```
wb.Navigate("Yourwebsite")
GoSub loading
.
.
.
loading:  
  ComObjError(false)     ;turn off com errors
  While value = "" {      
    value := wb.document.getElementsByClassname("somethingHere") [0].innerText 
    Continue
    }
  ComObjError(true)
Return
```

Without seeing more of your code and the website you are trying to work with, it will be difficult to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It worked... turns out it was the sleep time for the form to load. form was slower than Sleep 100 for some reason. Now, the form loads, but it is only taking 1 field. so password and email are not being filled.